# Find the non-intersecting values of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two numpy arrays and want to find the the non-intersecting values, how do I do it?

Here's a short example of what I can't figure out.

```
a = ['Brian', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Craig']
b = ['Andrew','Steve']
```

I want to find the non-intersecting values.  In this case I want my output to be:

```
['Brian','Craig']
```

The opposite of what I want is done with this:

```
c=np.intersect1d(a,b)
```

which returns

```
['Andrew' 'Steve']
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that none of the objects shown in your question are Numpy arrays, you don't need Numpy to achieve this:

```
c = list(set(a).symmetric_difference(b))
```

If you have to have a Numpy array as the output, it's trivial to create one:

```
c = np.array(set(a).symmetric_difference(b))
```

(This assumes that the order in which elements appear in `c` does not matter. If it does, you need to state what the expected order is.)

P.S. There is also a pure Numpy solution, but personally I find it hard to read:

```
c = np.setdiff1d(np.union1d(a, b), np.intersect1d(a, b))
```

Comment: The asker tagged the question numpy, so I thought there should be some explanation about why not to use numpy directly.

Comment: @simonzack: There is an explantation in the answer (which is: because it's not needed). Besides, the answer explicitly provides a way to construct a numpy array with the result.

Comment: @simonzack: why would you care whether a correct answer does or does not explicitly "use" numpy, in particular, when it works with numpy arrays?

Comment: thanks for this - all answers were very helpful - my fault for not using numpy arrays in the actual question - yikes, sorry.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `setxor1d`. According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setxor1d.html):

> Find the set exclusive-or of two arrays.
>   Return the sorted, unique values that are in only one (not both) of the input arrays.

Usage is as follows:

```
import numpy

a = ['Brian', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Craig']
b = ['Andrew','Steve']

c = numpy.setxor1d(a, b)
```

Executing this will result in `c` having a value of `array(['Brian', 'Craig'])`.

Answer (score 4):

```
np.setdiff1d(a,b)
```

This will return non intersecting value of first argument with second argument
Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,3]
np.setdiff1d(a,b)  -> returns [2]
np.setdiff1d(b,a)  -> returns []
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for python arrays

```
c=[x for x in a if x not in b]+[x for x in b if x not in a]
```

It first collects all the elements from a that are not in b and then adds all those elements from b that are not in a. This way you get all elements that are in a or b, but not in both.

Comment: Currently, this is listed as low quality answer. Perhaps you can improve it by explaining what does this code do (just a little bit is ok!)

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['Brian', 'Steve', 'Andrew', 'Craig'])
b = np.array(['Andrew','Steve'])
```

you can use

```
set(a) - set(b)
```

Output:

```
set(['Brian', 'Craig'])
```

Note: set operation returns unique values